# SQL performance consideration when using joins for DB design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have a table

name: `order`
with 
`id`, `product_id`, `comment`

now I want to add a state

new table: `order_state`
`1 -> finished`
`2 -> started`

etc

then add a field `order_state_id` in the table `order`

in what way do I have to worry about performance?

does this always perform well or what is the case where it wont? e.g. i mean when doing joins etc with a lot of orders, say 200'000 orders

i have used mysql views before and they were [horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515743/performance-considerations-when-using-mysql-views) the view I created contained obviously several joins. Is this not a related problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623852/why-are-joins-bad-when-considering-scalability/2623979#2623979

Comment: In this particular case, a separate table that stores just order_state which can take only a limited set of values would be wastefull and not high performance. The same data can be saved in the orders column just as easily. The level of redundancy will be exactly the same.

Comment: The order_state_id is a low-cadinality domain. You can implement it as a table (as in your question) or as a `CHECK` constraint, or as a true domain (don't know if mysql supports these), or as an enum (ditto). In all cases the storage requirements will typically be sizeof int, the domain-table version will probably imply a a supporting index for the foreign key to speed up cascades. Performance should not be a problem (the low cardinality will enable hash joins/lookups) (if mysql has these)

Comment: @joop - MySQL allows the `CHECK` syntax, but ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just too big for a comment

In addition to what have been said, consider partial indexes.

Some DB like Postgres and SQL Server allows you to create indexes that not only specifies columns but rows.

It seems that you will end up with a constant growing amount of orders with order_state_id equal to finished (2) a stable amount of orders with order_state_id equal to started (1)

If your business make use of queries like this

```
SELECT id, comment
  FROM order
 WHERE order_state_id =  1
  AND product_id = @some_value
```

Partial indexing allows you to limit the index, including only the unfinished orders

```
CREATE INDEX Started_Orders
          ON order(product_id)
       WHERE order_state_id = 1
```

This index will be smaller than the unfiltered contra part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/344/indexes/23954/partial-or-filtered-index#t=201609301908036679302

Comment: That link refers to features _not available in MySQL_.

Answer (score 0):

Don't normalize `order_state`.  Instead add this column

```
order_state ENUM('finished', 'started') NOT NULL
```

Then use it this way (for example):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE order_state = 'finished'
    ...
```

An `ENUM` (with up to 255 options) takes only 1 byte.  `INT` takes 4 bytes.  `TINYINT` takes 1 byte.

Back to your question...  There are good uses of `JOIN` and there are unnecessary uses.

Comment: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ i stopped reading at "3. It's impossible to add additional attributes or related info." because this would already have been a big killer for me before this

Comment: If you need to code a client application that has a Combobox to select order_state. What is the best approach to filling it with values without the need of a recompile if a new state (like 'Canceled') is added?

Comment: @Toskan - You can have another table with that enum as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  In it, you can have other column(s) with 'related info'.  Adding a new option _used to be_ a costly option.  Now it is almost instantaneous, regardless of table size.

Comment: @Horaciux - I haven't done a "recompile" in 15 years.  PHP, Perl, Java, VB, etc don't have a visible "compile" phase.  Are you using C#, C++, or some other old language?  Still, it can be 'automated', see next comment...

Comment: With the extra table or with the information_schema, you can discover the list of "order_states" and programmatically build the Combobox.

Comment: `information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_TYPE` is `"enum('GREEN','YELLOW','RED')"` in one example I found.  (OK, this I_S approach is rather messy.)

Comment: There are 3 approaches - ENUM, TINYINT, VARCHAR.  Each has pros and cons.  You have to decide.  (My answer is merely advocating for one of them.)

Comment: @RickJames that would mean duplicating the Enums, right? so if i want to rename yellow to say yellow/orange i would have to do it at two places

Comment: True, that's one of the drawbacks to `ENUM`.  Enum is a 'bad' choice when there are hundreds of options or they change a lot.